# vb.net only display line from richtextbox that contains a specific word

Tags: vb.net, line, contains

I have a richtextbox1 that containts lines of words.
I would like to copy lines from richtextbox1 that contains("x") into another textbox2. He is my noob code:

```
 Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
        For Each line As String In RichTextBox1.Text
            If line.Contains("x") Then
                RichTextBox2.Text = line
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

What is the problem plz?

Comment: Ok, and did you have a question?

Comment: @Plutonix , yes , Why my code doesnt workd :D

Comment: There are two things that should ALWAYS be done before posting here and you have apparently done neither.  The first is to read the relevant documentation and the second is to debug your code.  If you debug your code you'll see that `line` never contains what seem to think it should.  If you read the documentation for the `RichTextBox` class, you'll learn how to access the lines of text it contains.

Comment: `line` is just a string variable, it's your job to set its value. What if you changed that to `For Each word As String...` Do you expect it to magically iterate through the words of the text? How about `For Each paragraph`? The compiler doesn't understand English.

Comment: As a follow up to what @jmcilhinney  already said. When you're there (parsing the Docs), pay attention to what `.Lines` really means, or you might get the wrong result. `.Lines` always references the original text lines (separated by a Newline[CrLf][\r\n][0D0A]), not the (eventually) wrapped ones.

Comment: guys, it took me one hour to make this code which had no error inside.... Pff, forget about this question, thanks for your help. It will take me a day or more to find the solution.  @jimi: thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, i found the solution. it took me time but i did it :D
I post my solution, i hope it will help someone.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
            If RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Contains("YourWord") Then
                RichTextBox2.Text += (RichTextBox1.Lines(i)) + vbNewLine
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```